# ¿Es posible unir enumeraciones en C#?

Tags: c#, enum

Quiero hacer un Script génerico y me veo en esta tesitura. Resulata que tengo una serie de animaciones correspondiente a diferentes objetos muchas tienen identico nombre. Y me gustaría tenerlas juntas pero no revueltas... me explico, juntas para tener una variable "genérica" que me permita identifcar a todas ellas de una sola vez, pero a la vez que no estén revueltas para mantener cierto orden y no liarme. Se me ha ocurrido algo así.

```
//-----------------------------------------------
public class Animations
{
    public enum Player { idle = 0, destroy = 1 };
    public enum Enemy { idle = 2, destroy = 3 };
    public enum Car { idle = 4, destroy = 5 };
    public enum Dog { idle = 6, destroy = 7 };
};
//-----------------------------------------------
public struct UnionAnimations
{
     public Animations.Player player;
     public Animations.Enemy enemy;
     public Animations.Car car;
     public Animations.Dog dog;
};
//-----------------------------------------------
```

El tema que para acceder a cada miembro no me queda mas remedio que hacerlo así y ya no me sirve porque no es lo suficientemente génerico.

```
UnionAnimations unionAnimations;
int animationID = (int)unionAnimations.player;
```

Me podría servir si por ejemplo obtuviera el valor sin tener que poner ".player"... algo así.

```
UnionAnimations unionAnimations;
int animationID = (int)unionAnimations;
```

Estaría genial poder hacer una enumeración/unión de enumaraciones. Algo mas o menos así...

```
unum UnionAnimations{Animations.Player, Animations.Enemy, Animations.Car, Animations.Dog};
```

Pero esto no funciona o no se hacerlo correctamente.

¿Es posible hacer algo asi o un método equivalente para conseguir lo que busco?
Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Seria mejor tener solo un Enum  ejemplo:  AnimationType { none,idle, destroy},y un observer o detectar un cambio cada vez que un objeto tiene un cambio en esa propieda, excepto para cuando esta en none. Respecto tu pregunta pod

Comment: Gracias Miuel!! Creo que pillé la idea y creo que me puede servir!! saludos!!